# Buffering FFmpeg input in the RAM

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using file as an input and outputting a live stream, but my disk has a ton of I/O spikes(from other tools) so I wonder, **is there a "built in" way to buffer it in the FFmpeg memory?**

- *I can use named pipe with a buffer, but it might have an overhead.*
- *I have only 200-300 Mb RAM for this purpose so I can't cache the whole file.*

## Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried piping the input through the `buffer` command?

Comment: @EugenRieck I think It might work. I'll check if the machine has it. Probably gonna use it if there is no more straight forward solution.